# use dict from python in django html template and also in js

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am having a dict `statistics` in my `view.py` and give it as param in my `context` to my `index.html`. There I want to use it in my html like `{{ statistics.key1 }}`. But I also want to use it in `js`.

When using `json.dumps` like this in my `view.py`:

```
"statistics": json.dumps(statistics, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
```

I can use it like this in my `js`:

```
var statistics = JSON.parse('{{ statistics | escapejs }}');
```

But then I can't use it as a dict anymore in my html. Makes sense, as it is now a JSON-String.

But when I just pass it like a dict, I can use it in my html. but

```
var statistics = '{{ statistics | escapejs }}'
```

gives me a JSON with single quotes so I can't just parse it.

How can I do both? Still use the dict as normal in my HTML and also parse it to use it in js?

Comment: You could pass it to the template twice, under two different names, with one of them being the plain dictionary and one of them being the json string.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes of course. I thought about this solution too. But I considered it being not very clean. I'd really like to only pass it once.